# Spring, JPA : @LastModifiedDate is not updated with partial update done through @Query in JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have this function written for updating price of an item:

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE Item s SET s.price= :price, s.version= :version WHERE s.id= :id and s.version < :version")
void updatePrice(@Param("id") Long id, @Param("price") Double price, @Param("version") Long version);
```

Could it be because partial updates won't update @LastModifiedDate ?

Comment: have you included the @EnableJpaAuditing in the configuration file 

http://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa

Comment: Hi Where you able to fix this? How did you go about it?

Comment: Not really, I did it by manually creating date.

Comment: Same problem...

Comment: Same problem, I attempted a solution based on getting an EntityManager and taking entityManager.createNativeQuery but it was not successful